# Selenium IDE - Refresh until element is present

Tags: selenium-ide

I have to wait an uncertain amount of time for a task to complete & a new one to be created before I can continue with my script. So I have stuck in a very long pause before I refresh and then check to see if the link is available.

e.g.

|pause | 600000 | |

|refreshAndWait | | |

|clickAndWait | link=new | |

Unfortunately, this is all guess work so sometimes the script will continue and sometimes it will fail. Is there a command or some solution that can be used to refresh at certain intervals and continue to check if the link is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Selenium IDE Flow control to do it:

```
label               | Start
refresh
storeElementPresent | link=new          | trigger
gotoIf              | ${trigger}==false | Start
click               | link=new
```

Comment: Well this worked nicely! Using refresh did not work as the page was slow to load so it was an endless loop, but refreshAndWait did allow the link to finally display in order to meet the conditions to continue the script. Thank you for the solution!!